# After Ubuntu update MultiViews not work

Tags: php, apache-2.4, rewrite

After updated the Ubuntu distro, i have many problem, what i mostly fixed, except one.

I have apache 2 server, and MultiViews not woking. My website contain many url like this: (and i now got 404)

```
/heme/image.php/someimg.jpg
```

or

```
/heme/other.php/smoething?asd=bsd
```

or

```
/index.php/param1/param2/
```

and many other .php file work there like this.
I google-ed and tried many tips, but doesn't helped.

**mod_negotiation** is loaded (confirmed by phpinfo())
Option +MultiViews is setted for directory

I tried uncomment this lines in */etc/mime.types*, but if i do that, i got 
"**err_incomplete_chunked_encoding**" in browser, instead solve my problem.

```
#application/x-httpd-php                        phtml pht php
#application/x-httpd-php-source                 phps
#application/x-httpd-php3                       php3
#application/x-httpd-php3-preprocessed          php3p
#application/x-httpd-php4                       php4
#application/x-httpd-php5                       php5
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a .htaccess file to my html root folder. This is solved my problem. But i not understand kind of problem was that.

```
AcceptpathInfo On
Options MultiViews
MultiviewsMatch Handlers
```